# Git merge resolve conflict readability

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

Here I simply the situation.

I have a JSON file in master, with the content like this

```
[
  {
    "aa": {
      "type": "fixed",
      "something": {
        "a2": [
          "original1"
        ]
      }
    },
    "bb": {
      "type": "fixed",
      "something": {
        "b2": [
          "original2"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I create a branch from master and add an element to it, to become:

```
[
  {
    "aa": {
      "type": "fixed",
      "something": {
        "a2": [
          "original1"
        ]
      }
    },
    "bb": {
      "type": "fixed",
      "something": {
        "b2": [
          "original2"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "aa": {
      "type": "fixed",
      "something": {
        "a2": [
          "me1"
        ]
      }
    },
    "bb": {
      "type": "fixed",
      "something": {
        "b2": [
          "me2"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Someone also making a change to master like this

```
[
  {
    "aa": {
      "type": "fixed",
      "something": {
        "a2": [
          "original1"
        ]
      }
    },
    "bb": {
      "type": "fixed",
      "something": {
        "b2": [
          "original2"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "aa": {
      "type": "fixed",
      "something": {
        "a2": [
          "they1"
        ]
      }
    },
    "bb": {
      "type": "fixed",
      "something": {
        "b2": [
          "they2"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I try to merge my code to master, and of course, conflict occurs. Here I want to ask is, the original diff shows lots of fragment changes, instead of changes in the whole block. Can I 'tell' the differ to look at the changes in a more 'block' way to 'line' way for readability?

Current behaviour:

```
[
  {
    "aa": {
      "type": "fixed",
      "something": {
        "a2": [
          "original1"
        ]
      }
    },
    "bb": {
      "type": "fixed",
      "something": {
        "b2": [
          "original2"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "aa": {
      "type": "fixed",
      "something": {
        "a2": [
<<<<<<< HEAD
          "they1"
=======
          "me1"
>>>>>>> dc3d6b5 (x)
        ]
      }
    },
    "bb": {
      "type": "fixed",
      "something": {
        "b2": [
<<<<<<< HEAD
          "they2"
=======
          "me2"
>>>>>>> dc3d6b5 (x)
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

What I want:

```
[
  {
    "aa": {
      "type": "fixed",
      "something": {
        "a2": [
          "original1"
        ]
      }
    },
    "bb": {
      "type": "fixed",
      "something": {
        "b2": [
          "original2"
        ]
      }
    }
<<<<<<< HEAD
  },
  {
    "aa": {
      "type": "fixed",
      "something": {
        "a2": [
          "me1"
        ]
      }
    },
    "bb": {
      "type": "fixed",
      "something": {
        "b2": [
          "me2"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
=======
  {
    "aa": {
      "type": "fixed",
      "something": {
        "a2": [
          "they1"
        ]
      }
    },
    "bb": {
      "type": "fixed",
      "something": {
        "b2": [
          "they2"
        ]
      }
    }
>>>>>>> dc3d6b5 (x)
  }
]
```

Comment: Probably not, since the diff algorithm is designed to find the minimal differences. It's also greatly application or usecase specific how much context you'd want to include.

Comment: I have not read the entire [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/diff-options) but you might be able to find some combination of options that at least comes close.

Comment: Something like [Semantic merge](https://www.semanticmerge.com/) might be able to do this.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is both no and yes:<sup>1</sup>

- No, you can't get Git to do this.
- Yes, you can get diff-and-merge engines to do this.

Git contains a central diff engine—specifically a slightly hacked-up version of the [XDiff](http://xmailserver.org/xdiff-lib.html) code—and several merge engines, but it always breaks up the "symbols" that the diff engine uses<sup>2</sup> at *line* boundaries.

Changing it to use the right level of structural boundaries is theoretically possible.  In practice, figuring out what that level is, and doing all the actual work, is hard.

---

<sup>1</sup>"Go not to the Elves for counsel, for they will say both no and yes."

<sup>2</sup>The point of a diff engine is to find a reasonably-minimal solution to a [string-to-string edit problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-to-string_correction_problem).  The "string" is therefore simply a series of symbols: the symbols can be DNA "letters" such as GATTACA, or source code lines (perhaps minus whitespace), or whatever you like.  There are different algorithms for "small-alphabet symbol sets" (DNA/RNA) and for "large-alphabet sets" (source code lines).

If you make a "symbol" an entire JSON grouping, you'll get the differences you want.  *Combining* those differences, in a merge engine, is then the remaining trick.  Note that since JSON, or some of its cousins like XML, is a *structured* format, we might want diff and merge engines that consider structural moves, such as popping a subtree "out" one level.  Your particular example case does not need this, though.